# Error in integrating phonegap inapp purchase plugin on ios device

Tags: cordova

I have integrated in-app purchase from https://github.com/phonegap/phonegap-plugins/tree/master/iPhone/InAppPurchaseManager.

I am using xcode4.3 & cordova-1.5.0.

Me getting error:

> window.plugins.inAppPurchaseManager is undefined

So I am not able to call inAppPurchaseManager methods like requestProductData etc.

Answer (score 0):

"window.plugins.inAppPurchaseManager is **undefined**" means that the window.plugins.inAppPurchaseManager variable is not defined. It is defined in **InAppPurchaseManager.js**. 
It seems that you have forgotten to include the file InAppPurchaseManager.js in **your html code**:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/InAppPurchaseManager.js"></script>
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I sort out the issue. I renamed cordova to Cordova (capital C instead small ) in InAppPurchaseManager.js and now its working for me. But now I am getting new error: Invalid Product id. Please help me. Thanks & regards